# PHP Mail - UTF 8 Encoding problems with Chinese characters

Tags: encoding, utf-8, phpmailer, php

I have a PHP Mail script that sends out emails and I need to send some out in Chinese.  I have the following code:

```
$email_header = "From: $from\n";
$email_header .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; //1 UrgentMessage, 3 Normal
$email_header .= "Return-Path: <$return>\n";
$email_header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
mail($row["email"], '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $email_body, $email_header);
```

The issue I have is with both the Subject of the Email and the body - it is sending as follows:

```
Subject: ???????????

Body: ???????????????

?????

??????????????????????????????????????????????????

?????
```

Clearly not Chinese!!!  If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Comment: Most likely your data is broken (i.e. not utf-8) before you even get here.  What do you see when you `echo` rather than `mail`?  I say this because I have a practically identical script that works just fine for non-English characters.

Comment: Stored in the MySQL database as 'utf8_unicode_ci' and appears fine in there and on other pagers - will check Echo now.

Comment: OK, checked the Echo and it is the same, just a series if ?'s.  The .PHP page is set to UTF-8 as well. :-(

Comment: Do you do a `set names utf-8` query when you connect to the db?  May be necessary.

Comment: DOH! - pop that in as a solution AWM and I'll give you a tick of approval - thanks!  Been driving me nuts!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a database connection issue rather than a mailer issue.  Perhaps forgot to do a `set names utf-8`...?

Comment: Perfect :-) as my name suggests - DOH!